# User Properties has been deprecated in Facebook Analytics

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, firebase-analytics, facebook-analytics, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

We are trying to integrate Facebook analytics into our apps and we notice that user properties has been deprecated on 22 Jun 2020. But [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/send_data/user_properties/#user-properties) doesn't not say anything about the alternative way. Is there any means to add new user properties like [this in Firebase analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9269570)?

Comment: have you found any solution?